# Picking the Empid which has max sequence number=-1 for 8 quarters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table "summary" which has the following information

```
Sumid(pk) Empid(fk)  Year   Quarter    Seqnumber amount
101        1001      2015      1          -1      1000
102        1001      2015      1           0      2000
103        1001      2015      1           1      3000
104        1001      2015      1           2      4000
105        1002      2015      1           -1     6000
105        1002      2015      2           -1     7000
105        1002      2015      3           -1     8000
105        1002      2015      4           -1     9000
105        1002      2016      1           -1     10000
105        1002      2016      2           -1     11000
105        1002      2016      3           -1     12000
105        1002      2016      4           -1     13000
Output:

Empid(fk)
1002
```

Bussiness rule: We need to pick the Empid whose max(Seqnumber)=-1 down the line for 8 quarters(going backward)
i.e In this example 1002 starting from 2016 fourth quarter to 2015 first quarter it has only "-1"
as max(seqnumber) ,so we need to pick that empid .

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: sql server 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012+, you can just count them using window functions:

```
select distinct empid;
from (select t.*,
             max(seqnum) over (partition by empid rows between 7 preceding and current row) as max_seqnum8
      from t
     ) t
where max_seqnum8 = -1
```

Comment: @MunnaDonepudi A slight variation of this that should work for your needs: http://rextester.com/QLGV94647

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this if quarters >= 8**

```
SELECT 
Empid
FROM summary
WHERE Empid NOT IN 
(
SELECT Empid FROM summary GROUP BY Empid HAVING MAX(Seqnumber) <> -1
)
GROUP BY Empid
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 8
```

**You can use this if quarters = 8**

```
SELECT 
Empid
FROM summary
WHERE Empid NOT IN 
(
SELECT Empid FROM summary GROUP BY Empid HAVING MAX(Seqnumber) <> -1
)
GROUP BY Empid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;With cte(Sumid,Empid,[Year],[Quarter],Seqnumber,amount)
AS
(
SELECT 101, 1001,2015 ,1,1  ,1000  Union all
SELECT 102, 1001,2015 ,1,0  ,2000  Union all
SELECT 103, 1001,2015 ,1,1  ,3000  Union all
SELECT 104, 1001,2015 ,1,2  ,4000  Union all
SELECT 105, 1002,2015 ,1,-1 ,6000  Union all
SELECT 105, 1002,2015 ,2,-1 ,7000  Union all
SELECT 105, 1002,2015 ,3,-1 ,8000  Union all
SELECT 105, 1002,2015 ,4,-1 ,9000  Union all
SELECT 105, 1002,2016 ,1,-1 ,10000 Union all
SELECT 105, 1002,2016 ,2,-1 ,11000 Union all
SELECT 105, 1002,2016 ,3,-1 ,12000 Union all
SELECT 105, 1002,2016 ,4,-1 , 13000 
)
SELECT TOP 1  Empid From
--MAX(CountSeqnumber)OVER(PARTITION BY Empid ORDER BY Empid Desc) AS MaxSeq 
(
SELECT  *, COUNT(Seqnumber)Over(Partition by Empid Order by Empid) AS CountSeqnumber FROM cte
)Dt
ORDER BY Dt.Empid DESC
```